# How to copy AND add clipboard contents to text area

Tags: javascript

```
var content = clipboardData.getData("Text");
    document.forms["test"].elements["clipboard"].value = content;
}
```

I would like to copy the clipboard contents to a textarea and add it each time instead of replacing the text. I have no issues copying the stuff there just can't figure out how to add rather than replace. Prefer Javascript.

Comment: `document.forms["test"].elements["clipboard"].value += content;`

Comment: Worked! How can I get it to add to the next line though?

Comment: Add a new line before the text. ... += '\n' + content;

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I had posted the question days ago. Thank you for the prompt and accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

try this script [clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js)

You can copy, cut, paste, use different settings ;)